# Replace the ' by \'

Tags: java, replace

I'm trying to replace a single quote `'` with this character `\'`, the final goal is to transform this **chay'ekka** to **chay\'ekka**. I tried this code:

```
String cityName = new String("chay'ekka");
System.out.println("before : " + cityName);
cityName = cityName.replaceAll("'", "\\'");
System.out.println("after : " + cityName);
```

but the result is still **chay'ekka**.

Are there any other methods or functions in java to achieve this goal?

Comment: Note that the `replace` method replaces **all occurrences** too. The only difference to `replaceAll` is that it does not use regex. So `replace` is the method you want to use here.

Comment: ***Don't!!!!!*** use the `String` constructor. just write `"chay'ekka"`

Comment: Usage of the `String` constructor prevents strings from being pulled out of javas internal string cache. There are only few scenarios where you want this.

Comment: @ekka read the comment from Zabuka above yours. The use case range is pretty narrow and it doesn't benefit you at all

Comment: ok thank you @Zabura

Comment: but i have a small problem , when i write this in file i get **chay\\'ekka**

Comment: @Zabura what i need is chay\'ekka

Answer (score 14):

You're using `replaceAll`, which works with regular expressions. While you *can* fix that by doubling the backslashes, there's no indication that you want regular expressions at all. It would be simpler just to call [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) instead, as that doesn't use regular expressions:

```
String cityName = new String("chay'ekka");
System.out.println("before : " + cityName);
cityName = cityName.replace("'", "\\'");
System.out.println("after : " + cityName);
```

Note that `replace` still replaces all occurrences of the first argument with the second argument - the naming between `replace` and `replaceAll` is poor :( It would be better as `replace` vs `replaceRegex` or something similar.

Comment: You could also add that this might outperform `replaceAll` as this option doesn't require invoking the overhead of a regex engine.  Just saying.

Comment: I think it is worth highlighting that `replace` replaces **all** occurrences too. I've seen many people using `replaceAll` only because they thought `replace` only changes the first occurrence.

Comment: thank you very much that's work also, but I need to know: is String.replace don't work with regulars expressions ??

Comment: @ekka: It's not that it doesn't "work with" - but the *inputs* aren't regular expression patterns. If you *do* want to use regular expressions, use `replaceAll` instead (or the methods on `Pattern`).

Comment: @Zabuza: Right, I've put that in.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I'm not sure it's worth including in the answer, but it's there as the first comment, so :)

Answer (score 6):

You need four backslashes to represent a single literal backslash:

```
String cityName = new String("chay'ekka");
System.out.println("before : "+cityName);
cityName = cityName.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'");
System.out.println("after : "+cityName);
```

The explanation for why *four* backslashes are needed is that `\\` represents a single literal backslash.  But, in a regex context, backslash itself needs to be escaped, so we need four of them.

Comment: Can you add an explanation to the answer why that is the case?

Comment: When I first saw your answer, didn't it explain *why* you needed four backslashes here, namely because `replaceAll` uses regular expressions? Without that information, the answer reads a bit strangely.

Comment: Good, but out-skeeted once again.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace function

```
System.out.println("chay'ekka".replace("'","\\'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `String#replace` instead. the `replaceAll` method works with regular expressions, which you are not using. So, this will turn into

```
String cityName = new String("chay'ekka");
System.out.println("before : "+cityName);
cityName = cityName.replace("'", "\\'");
System.out.println("after : "+cityName);
```

However, you should not be instantiating new strings with `new String`. Instead, just do `String cityName = "chay'ekka";`